# ConstraintViolationException on non-nullable @ManyToOne, but inserting value when removing constraint

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

I'm working with spring-data over hibernate. I have a very strange behaviour inserting new records in a @ManyToOne relationship. I got a ConstraintViolationException for a non-null column, that's ok because the column cannot be null. The problem is that the value on the entity is not null and the stranger thing, if I remove the constraint from the database, hibernate insert the correct value, no null column inserted!
I'll let you the scenario I'm dealing with, simple reservation schema, where 1 reservation can have multiple seats and each seat have their own exit (that's where the problem is).

**Reservation**

```
@Entity
public class Reservation {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="reservation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ReservationSeat> seats;

    ...
}
```

**ReservationSeat**

```
@Entity
public class ReservationSeat {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_seat__exit"))
    private Stop exit;

    ...
}
```

**Stop**

```
@Entity
public class Stop {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

The problem exists on **ReservationSeat** > **exit**, if I remove the **nullable = false** (and drop the constraint on database) no exception is thrown, **BUT THE COLUMN IS POPULATED CORRECTLY**. If I add the non-null constraint on database and/or on the code, I got the ConstraintViolationException with the exact same execution code.
Does Hibernate insert an empty record ant then update it? Can someone help me understand what's going on?

**EDIT**

There's a simplification of the flow where I got this error.

```
@Transactional
public void addReservation(){
    Stop stop1 = new Stop(1);
    Stop stop2 = new Stop(2);

    stopRespository.save(stop1);
    stopRespository.save(stop2);

    Reservation reservation1 = new Reservation();
    Reservation reservation2 = new Reservation();

    ReservationSeat reservation1Seat = new ReservationSeat();
    ReservationSeat reservation2Seat = new ReservationSeat();

    reservation1Seat.setExit(stop1);
    reservation2Seat.setExit(stop2);

    reservation1.getSeats().add(reservation1Seat);
    reservation2.getSeats().add(reservation2Seat);

    List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList();
    reservations.add(reservation1);
    reservations.add(reservation2);

    reservationRepository.saveAll(reservations);
}
```

The code runs well, but I guess is when spring data flushes the transaction the ConstraintViolationException happens.

Comment: What is the name of FK column in Seat table?

Comment: Hi Peter, exit_id. And that's where I got the error, violation of non-null constraint on "exit_id"

Comment: It is unidirectional mapping?

Comment: Yes, seat has a exit_id but stop does not have a seat_id or any relation to seat

Comment: See my edit, I've added the execution flow.

Comment: @rmpt We're seeing something very similar - did you find a solution that didn't involve removing the constraints?

Comment: unfortunately no